# Virtualization- Regarding Hypervisors

Tags: hypervisor

If my system is running 2 OSs like Ubuntu and Windows, does it mean that my system has a Hypervisor installed into it by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Opinion:
No ,it does not mean that, since hypervisors are of 2 types and what I think that you are confused with Type-1 hypervior , which is bare metal native , it works on hardware, create a virtual hardware image  and allows more than 1 OS to work on same hardware ,Eg. of type-1 are 
VMware ESX and ESXi ,Microsoft Hyper-V,Citrix Systems XenServer. But as in your case you can do it without installing a hypervior also ,by making partioning of file system.